# como hacer que suceda un evento cuando cualquiera de los checkbox este checked o y otro cuando ninguno este checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy usando if y else para hacer que aparesca un elemento cuando cualquiera de los checkbox este checked y que desaparezca cuando ninguno esta checked y estoy usando este metodo no funciona

```js
 $( 'intput' ).is( 'checked', true, function() {
  if ($(this).is()(':checked') ){
    setflag = ture;
    $('#scale-demo').removeClass('scale-out');
}
else if($("intput").is('checked') ) {
    $('#scale-demo').addClass('scale-out');
}
});
```

no se exactamente como decirle que cuando cualquier input sea true añada la clase y si ninguno esta checado que desaparesca añadiendo esa clase "scale-out"

Answer (score 0):

ten cuidado cuando escribes, input - no intput; también true y no ture.

Prueba con esto.

```
$('input').on('click', function () {        
        if ($('input').is(':checked')) {
            setflag = true;
            $('#scale-demo').removeClass('scale-out');
        } else {
            $('#scale-demo').addClass('scale-out');
        }
    });
```